# Search for a string inside a text file and replace it with another string

Tags: c#, replace, streamreader, streamwriter

Im trying to replace a line within a text file with another line. As an example the text file can look like the following:

```
defaultServerList;data.dat
mcResSkin:something_that_can_vary.zip
```

Say that i want to replace whatever is after "mcResSkin:" with something other so that it will end up looking like this

```
mcResSkin:default.zip
```

How can i do this? As far is a have understood, you need to read the whole file first, and then write it out again once you have made your changes. But im unsure how to do the above. This is what i have:

```
try
{
    var content = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(selectedPath + "\\settings.txt"))
    {
         content = reader.ReadToEnd();
         reader.Close();
    }

    newcontent = Regex.Replace(something_to_replace_the_whole_line);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(selectedPath + "\\settings.txt"))
    {
         writer.Write(newcontent);
         writer.Close();
    }
}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: What is not working with the code you posted?

Comment: How big are the files, will the whole file fit in memory?

Comment: Your approach is valid although not optimal for big files. Are you asking for the correct regex?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question was just the Regex i needed to figure out. But i managed to do it by using the following Regex

```
string newcontent = Regex.Replace(content, ".*mcResSkin:.*", "mcResSkin:default.zip\n");
```

Just updating it for others to see